# How to use either CFSAVECONTENT or CFHTTP to save external Javascript results

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfhttp

I have the following javascript.

```
<SCRIPT SRC="http://www.world66.com/export/export.js" LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT"></SCRIPT>


<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">  
Header_Color = "Black";
Header_Size = "5";
Header_Face = "arial,helvetica";    
Nav_Color = "Black";
Nav_Size = "4";
Nav_Face = "arial,helvetica";   
Body_Color = "Black";
Body_Size = "4";
Body_Face = "arial,helvetica";  
printGuide('mauritius','someemail@somwehere.com');
</Script>
```

I want to preferably use CFSAVECONTENT to save the output of the javascript. Can someone please assist?

Comment: Javascript is client side. ColdFusion is server side. There is no clean way to do this. I supposed you could run NodeJS and have ColdFusion interact with that. Would you should do is consider what `http://www.world66.com/export/export.js` is doing and just start doing that in ColdFusion

Comment: I have had a look at the .js but can't figure out how to get the result.

Comment: Pop in a JS handler that takes the output (innerhtml or whatever) and AJAX posts it to another CF action. If you can't just do it in CF to begin with for some reason.

Comment: What have you have tried so far? If you have not tried anything yet, it looks like the function calls a url with some parameters. Start with cfhttp and construct a call with the parameters named in the script. If you run into errors, post back with your current code and any error messages.